# RSAT Server manager cannot manage domain controller in Azure

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2022, rsat

I have DC1 VM in Azure and DC2 VM on site. I tried everything I could think of but I cannot get this to work. On my domain signed pc I have server manager installed but I can not manage DC1 from that pc.

[image: Server manager]

Any suggestions on what I can try? I can normally browse DC1 through windows explorer. Firewall ports are open and winrm is listening

Comment: How are you connecting from your machine to the DC? VPN, Express Route? DC Exposed to the internet (I hope not)

Comment: Hi, I connect through site to site VPN. I can access all servers and services but not DC through server manager. I can connect with remote desktop on private ip.

Comment: DC is running server core 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in your screenshot there is a message about WinRM needing verification. WinRM runs on ports 5985,5986. There might be some firewall rule blocking these ports from your PC to DC01. Check also NSG rules on the Azure VM.

WinRM should be listening by default on all recent Windows Server versions but you can also run 'winrm quickconfig' on DC01 to verify status.

Finally run 'winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener' on DC01 to confirm that WinRM is listening on the correct port.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I forgot about nsg, I tried everything on firewall and all rules worked on policy tester but after checking nsg it really work now. Thank you